# How to find the nuget package that contains an assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

I feel like a) I should know the answer already and b) this would be a common question, but I can't find the answer.

I want to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest` in a .NET Standard 2.0 class library project.  Ok, I guessed I might need the `Microsoft.AspNetCore` package, but no that class isn't in any assembly in there apparently.

I can go on MSDN and see that the `HttpRequest` class is in

```
Namespace:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
Assembly:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll
```

So how do I find the package that holds `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll`?

I'm asking for the methodology, not just the package.

Comment: In most cases it seem to be as easy as in the answers. Some are hiding pretty well: Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=5.0.0.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From within Visual Studio, you can open the Nuget Package Manager and search for the class you want to use and the results will populate with the package you need.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem Microsoft has provided a way to see exactly what assemblies are included in a package, but the publisher will sometimes include that information in the package description, like Microsoft has in the example below:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions

The result is: 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For Microsoft released packages for the framework the naming is pretty simple, the name of the dll ***is*** the name of the package so the place to find `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll` is [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions)